# vba Vlookup Type MisMatch

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm using a vlookup in my code below but it's bringing up a type mismatch.  I've changed all the usuals, making the variable variant, changing it to application rather than worksheet function, but I still get the error.  Can anyone spot what I've done wrong please?

```
Sub createSQL()

Dim Br As Range
Dim Branch As Variant
Dim Rep As Range
Dim Report As Variant
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim SQLCode As Range
Dim SQLCode2 As String
Dim SQLCode3 As String
Dim BranchID As Long
Dim Exception As String
Dim ExCode As Variant

Set Br = Sheets("sheet3").Range("D2:D5")
SQLCode3 = Sheets("Issues").Range("F2")
SQLCode2 = Sheets("Issues").Range("F3")

For Each Branch In Br

RowNo = Branch.Row
Set SQLCode = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("L" & RowNo)
BranchID = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & RowNo)
SQLCode = SQLCode3 & BranchID & SQLCode2

Set Rep = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("I" & RowNo & ":K" & RowNo).Columns

For Each Report In Rep

If Report <> "" Then
SQLCode = SQLCode & Report
Else
SQLCode = ""

End If

ExCode = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & RowNo) & Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & RowNo) & Cells(1, Report.Column)

Exception = Application.VLookup(ExCode, Sheets("Exceptions").Range("D2:E2"), 2, False)

SQLCode = SQLCode & Exception & " Union All "

Next Report
SQLCode = Left(SQLCode, Len(SQLCode) - 10)

Next Branch

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of  `ExCode`?

Comment: it will be similar to something like this; 0R V WallisZero Commission

Comment: Your `Exception` variable is a String. `Application.VLookup` will not necessarily return as a String, for example if there is an error (ie. no match) it will return an `Error` object. You could use [`VarType`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VarType-Function-1e08636c-1892-40c2-aff3-2b894389e82d) to check the type of object `Application.VLookup` is returning and handle appropriately, or set `Exception` as a Variant.

Comment: The first problem is that it's supposed to be `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`. And what kind of data (not the variable type) are ExCode and the result of the Vlookup that you put in Exception? If you set both as String, it might work! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that it's supposed to be `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.

The second is that `VLookUp` may return an Error and this won't go into any string, so you'll have to test it before assigning it to `Exception`.

And I just tilted on that but you are trying to do a **vertical** lookup on **only one row**... It's most certainly the source of the error, as you won't find a lot of different things in one row...

If you set both `ExCode` and `Exception` as String, it might work with this code :

```
Dim LookUp_Range As Range
Set LookUp_Range = Sheets("Exceptions").Range("D2:E10")


If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ExCode, LookUp_Range, 2, False)) Then
    Exception = "Error"
Else
    Exception = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ExCode, LookUp_Range, 2, False)
End If
```

So your whole code will look like this :

```
Sub createSQL()

Dim Br As Range
Dim Branch As Variant
Dim Rep As Range
Dim Report As Variant
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim SQLCode As Range
Dim SQLCode2 As String
Dim SQLCode3 As String
Dim BranchID As Long
Dim Exception As String
Dim ExCode As String
Dim LookUp_Range As Range

Set Br = Sheets("sheet3").Range("D2:D5")
SQLCode3 = Sheets("Issues").Range("F2")
SQLCode2 = Sheets("Issues").Range("F3")

Set LookUp_Range = Sheets("Exceptions").Range("D2:E10")

With Sheets("Sheet3")
    For Each Branch In Br
        RowNo = Branch.Row
        Set SQLCode = .Range("L" & RowNo)
        BranchID = .Range("C" & RowNo)
        SQLCode = SQLCode3 & BranchID & SQLCode2
        Set Rep = .Range("I" & RowNo & ":K" & RowNo).Columns
        For Each Report In Rep
            If Report <> "" Then
                SQLCode = SQLCode & Report
            Else
                SQLCode = ""
            End If
            ExCode = .Range("C" & RowNo) & .Range("D" & RowNo) & Cells(1, Report.Column)
            If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ExCode, LookUp_Range, 2, False)) Then
                Exception = "Error"
            Else
                Exception = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ExCode, LookUp_Range, 2, False)
                'Concatenate only if there is a match!
                SQLCode = SQLCode & Exception & " Union All "
            End If
        Next Report
        SQLCode = Left(SQLCode, Len(SQLCode) - 10)
    Next Branch
End With
End Sub
```